# Error de compilación y de funcionamiento en programa que imprima al revés un número entero

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un programa que imprima un número pedido al usuario, al revés. Por ejemplo si es el 16, devolverá el 61 o si es el 1020, devolverá el 0201.
Resulta que cuando compilo el programa en P1++ me da estos errores:

```
program.cc: In function ‘int main()’:

program.cc:22:21: error: ‘unit’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   22 |     reversed_number += unit;

      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~

program.cc:18:24: error: ‘number_with_zeros’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   18 |        reversed_number += number_with_zeros;

      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

y en g++ me lo compila pero si inserto el 16 me devuelve el 121.

El código es el siguiente: (trato de usar solo las estructuras más básicas para realizarlo).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    int selection_number_division = number;
    int multiplication_division = number;
    int reversed_number = 0;
    int number_with_zeros, unit;

    while (selection_number_division > 0) {
        multiplication_division = selection_number_division % 10;
        for (int i = 10; i <= selection_number_division; i *= 10) {
            number_with_zeros = multiplication_division * i;
        }
       reversed_number += number_with_zeros;
       unit = selection_number_division % 10;
       selection_number_division /= 10;
    }
    reversed_number += unit;
    cout << reversed_number << endl;
}
```

Comment: "all warnings being treated as errors"... Por otra parte, ¿ejecutaste paso a paso tu programa? La depuración (_debug_) es clave aquí.

Comment: Si no quieres que trate las advertencias cómo errores quítale el parámetro que agregaste para que eso suceda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He tratado de simplificar tu código para que sea un poco más legible. También cambié el nombre de las variables, ya que son muy largas y a simple vista no lograba entender bien la lógica y donde estaba el problema. Podrías hacerlo así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number; // Definimos la variable "number" como int.

    cout << "digite un numero: ";
    cin >> number; // Almacenamos en la variable lo que escribimos.

    int reversa = 0; // Inicializamos la variable reversa.

    while (number > 0) // Hacemos un ciclo while en base a "number".
    {
        // La operación hace que el último dígito de "number" vaya en la primera
        // posición, así sucesivamente hasta terminar el ciclo while.
        reversa = reversa * 10 + (number % 10);
        number = number / 10;
    }

    // Pintamos el resultado en pantalla
    cout << "el numero invertido es: " << reversa << endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// digite un numero: 123456
// el numero invertido es: 654321

// digite un numero: 558494
// el numero invertido es: 494855
```

Comment: Me parece que deberías responder por qué se producen los errores. Considera esto: *Tienes una casa a la que debes hacer reparaciones. Luego llega alguien y te dice "¿Para qué repararla cuando puedes comprar una nueva"?* En ambos casos dejas el problema de lado y no lo arreglas.

Comment: @Mateo Soluciones para un problema, hay muchas, ahora te pregunto, ¿Qué tal si estás realizando una solución mucho más compleja que otra y encima estás estancado en muchos errores? ¿Te conviene seguir investigando el problema o ir por otra solución más simplificada, legible y fácil de entender?, o mejor dicho, **intentarlo de otra manera**. De hecho, dan los mismos resultados. :s...

Comment: No digo que esté mal buscar otro camino. Nosotros entendemos lo que el compilador nos quiere decir, pero el probablemente no. A lo que me refiero es que estaría bien explicar que surgen porque hay dos variables que se usan sin haber sido inicializadas. Quizá debí haber escrito esto en primer lugar xd